# redux-saga testing with tape

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-saga

I am trying to do testing on redux-saga. When I do generator.next(data).value for some unknown reason, the data is not passed onto the saga function as follows:

```
const gen = onCreateMessage()

const message = "aa"

gen.next(message).value
```

///SAGA FUNCTION

```
export function* onCreateMessage(message) {

    yield put(addMessage(message.payload))
```

Error message. Cannot read payload of undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your generator function accepts the `message` as an argument so you need to pass that when initializing the generator:

```
const gen = onCreateMessage( /* the message */ )
```

You'd then be able to get the next value by doing `gen.next().value` and verifying your assertion.

Here's a JS Bin with an example:  http://jsbin.com/catisu/edit?js,console

```js
const { put, take } = ReduxSaga.effects;
const { expect } = chai;

const createMessage = message => ({
  type: 'CREATE_MESSAGE',
  payload: message,
});

const addMessage = message => ({
  type: 'ADD_MESSAGE',
  payload: message,
});

function* onCreateMessage(message) {
  yield put(addMessage(message.payload));
}

// In your test
const message = 'some message';

// Message is passed when the generator is initialized
const gen = onCreateMessage(createMessage(message))
let next = gen.next();

// Using Chai here but with tape it'd be the same concept
try {
  expect(next.value).to.eql(
    put(addMessage(message))
  );
  
  console.log('It works!');
} catch(e) {
  console.error('bummer');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/redux-saga@0.11.1/dist/redux-saga.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/3.5.0/chai.min.js"></script>
```

Also small thing, but it also looks like your generator is expecting an object with a `payload` key, so a plain string won't work.

Comment: Thanks, passing in message when initialising the generator works but I thought I could pass in message at 
gen.next(message).value as for example http://joelhooks.com/blog/2016/03/20/build-an-image-gallery-using-redux-saga
I also have to use const gen = onCreateMessage(createMessage(message)) instead of const gen = onCreateMessage( /* the message */ ) because my onCreateMessage is expecting message.payload 
where I am guessing 'payload' key is automatically included in  { createAction } from 'redux-actions'?? I used it like this - export const createMessage = createAction(CREATE_MESSAGE);

Comment: Sorry I think I get it now - I was confused betw the generator function vs the function inside yield put that I am calling with gen.next()

Comment: Yep sounds like you're on the right track.  You're right, the `createAction` from `redux-actions` will automatically make an object with a `payload` key.